# Button change when user submit form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this 2 button which is save and saving...

```
<div ng-switch on="isLoading">
 <div ng-switch-when="true">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block disabled">Saving ...</button>
 </div>

 <div ng-switch-when="false">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="!allowSubmit(addUser)" ng-click="add();">Save</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

What i want is that before user click to submit the form, button remain as 'save' and after user click that save button it will change to 'saving...' button for 2 seconds. I tried and planning to use $timeout but it turns out the whole form got delayed for 2 seconds.

```
    $dialogScope.add = function() {
                if ($dialogScope.user.password != $dialogScope.user.confirmpassword && $dialogScope.user.username) {
                    $dialogScope.hasError = true
                    $dialogScope.errorMessage = "Password does not match";
                    return $dialogScope.errorMessage;
                }
                var copy = angular.copy($dialogScope.user);
            }
            $timeout(function() {
                $dialogScope.hasError = false;
                $scope.users.push(copy);
                $dialogScope.closeThisDialog();
            }, 2000);
```

how i suppose to do that?

Comment: Can I see where are you doing your request ? the code that is after the timeout

Comment: By the way, there is a bunch of ways you could do those things (validation, error messages, loading message, ...) in a cleaner/nicer way. After a quick Google search I found [this](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/processing-forms-in-angularjs) for instance. Didn't check it out in detail but you might get some nice ideas from it

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I did not test it but something like that should work

```
$dialogScope.add = function() {
    if ($dialogScope.user.password != $dialogScope.user.confirmpassword &&
      $dialogScope.user.username) 
    {
        $dialogScope.hasError = true
        $dialogScope.errorMessage = "Password does not match";
        return $dialogScope.errorMessage;
    }
    var copy = angular.copy($dialogScope.user);

    $dialogScope.hasError = false;
    $scope.users.push(copy);
    $dialogScope.closeThisDialog();
    $scope.isLoading = true;

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    }, 2000);
}
```

Feel free to comment if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-switch is not necessary.

I would do this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-switch-when="true">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block disabled">{{btnText}}</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$dialogScope.btnText = 'save';
$dialogScope.add = function() {
                if ($dialogScope.user.password != $dialogScope.user.confirmpassword && $dialogScope.user.username) {
                    $dialogScope.hasError = true
                    $dialogScope.errorMessage = "Password does not match";
                    return $dialogScope.errorMessage;
                }
                var copy = angular.copy($dialogScope.user);
                $dialogScope.btnText = 'saving...';
            }
            $timeout(function() {
                $dialogScope.hasError = false;
                $scope.users.push(copy);
                $dialogScope.closeThisDialog();
                $dialogScope.btnText = 'save';
            }, 2000);
```

Comment: it gives me an error instead angular.js:12477 Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngSwitch&p1=ngSwitchWhen

Comment: This is Controller error. 
To answer I need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do the save thing with loading icon. Button should say saving when processing. You can also do this using a variable.

For Example ;

**Before Button Click**

```
$scope.loading = false;
```

**On Button Click**

```
$scope.loading = true;
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">    
    <span data-ng-hide="loading"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save</span>
    <span data-ng-show="loading"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>Saving</span>    
</button>
```